# i want to remove tooltip title and i use following code `$(".picker__weekday").attr('title','');` but it is only work when open date picker

Tags: jquery, html, pickadate

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsXe1.png), [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd48d.png)

html code is,

```
<div class="cols-3">
   <div class="input input--large label js-label">
      <label for="" id="start_date_lable" class="active">Insurance Start Date</label>
      <span class="icon-calendar" id='start_date_icon'></span>
      <input type="text" name="motor_search[start_date]" id="motor_search_start_date" placeholder="Insurance Start Date">
   </div>
</div>
```

Removed tooltip title but it is only working when first open after that tooltip show. I used the following code but it did not work.

**Jquery code is,**

```
$(".picker__weekday").attr('title','');
$(document).ready(function(){
   var today = new Date();
   var nyr = new Date();
   var prevDate = nyr.setYear(nyr.getFullYear()-90);
   var m = parseInt(prevDate);
   var finDate = new Date();
   finDate.setTime(m);
   var dobPicker = $('#motor_search_year_make').pickadate({
      today: false,
      clear: false,
      close: false,
      selectMonths: true,
      selectYears: 90,
      min:finDate,
      max:new Date(),
      labelMonthNext: '',
      labelMonthPrev: '',
      labelMonthSelect: '',
      labelYearSelect: '',
      hiddenSuffix: '',
      clear: true,
      format: 'dd mmmm yyyy',
      formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      weekdaysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
      disable: [
         { from: [0,0,0], to: finDate }
      ],
      onClose: function(){
         this.$node.prev('label').removeClass('active');
      },
      onOpen: function(){
         $(".picker__weekday").attr('title','');
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: which library is used, to tooltip?

Comment: You mean you want to remove the week day ?
so your calendar not display
'Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'

Comment: no if we hover in week day they will show a title, i want to remove that

Comment: Which library are you using for datepicker? I guess you can find an option to disable/enable tooltip for datepicker in its documentation.

Comment: jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.1.9

Comment: It is pickadate.js http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/   no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css:

```
.picker__weekday{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or just put full name as empty using this option

```
weekdaysFull: [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ]
```

Comment: thanx Sebri Zouhaier

Comment: I needed to use this css selector to make it work: .pika-single .pika-table abbr[title] {
    pointer-events: none;
}